# I am facing "npm run dev" missing script issues. How to resolve it?

Tags: vue.js

I am currently in the folder E:\Learn\app-code-vue

```
E:\Learn\app-code-vue>npm run dev
npm ERR! Missing script: "dev"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Shrikant Rana\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-24T14_
26_36_332Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Do you mean `npm run serve` or `npm run start`? The issue stems from your package.json missing any script called `dev`

Answer (score 3):

See the scripts that are configured with Vue CLI 3 in the `package.json` file

```
"scripts": {
         "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
         "build": "vue-cli-service build",
         "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"    },
```

so you can run by use this : `npm run serve`

Answer (score 1):

Check your package.json file and see if you have dev named in your `"scripts"` key. This is what your `package.json` script tag should look like if you want to run a dev command:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

use `npm run serve`

It's working for me

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check if you are really in the correct folder